# Converting string into dictionary containing sets

Tags: python

I have a string in format below:

```
inp="({A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)})"
```

`{A,B,C}` represents nodes in the graph.

`{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}` represent the connected nodes.

I want to convert this string into a dictionary like this :

```
graph = {'A': set(['B','C']),
        'B': set(['C','A']),
        'C': set(['A','B'])}
```

`set` contains the nodes to which `key` node is connected.

`A` is connected to `B`.
`B` is connected to `C` and `C is connected to`A`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean for the nodes in `inp` to be `{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}`?

Comment: Those are connections.

Comment: I mean, you messed up the first node.

Comment: Is it 'A': set(['B'] or should be 'A': set(['C'] ?

Comment: Sorry It was a mistake. I have edited it.

Comment: {(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)} or {(B,C),(C,A),(A,B)} ?

Comment: Is this a directed graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex, lambda functions and list comprehensions to the rescue:

```
import re
inp="({A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)})"

m = re.search("{(.*?)},{\((.*?)\)}",inp)

nodes = m.group(1).split(',')
edges = map(lambda x:x.split(','), m.group(2).split('),('))
graph = {}

for i in nodes:
 graph[i]=set([edge[edge.index(i)-1] for edge in edges if i in edge])

print graph
```

Gives:

```
{'A': set(['C', 'B']), 'C': set(['A', 'B']), 'B': set(['A', 'C'])}
```

The pattern matching based on the input format is a little hacky, but will work if you remove the spaces. It also works perfectly fine if the edges have multi-character names.

And because all the cool kids seem to be about single list comprehensions, here it is in 3 lines (2 if you exclude the input):

```
inp="({A,B,CC},{(A,B),(B,CC),(CC,A)})"
nodes,edges = inp[2:-3].split('},{(')
graph = dict([(i,set([edge[edge.index(i)-1] for edge in map(lambda x:x.split(','), edges.split('),(')) if i in edge])) for i in nodes.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution

```
inp = "({A,B,C},{(A,C),(B,C),(C,A)})"
nodes,edges = inp[2:-2].split('},{')
nodes = nodes.split(',')
edges = [x.split(',') for x in edges[1:-1].split('),(')]
graph = dict([(node,set()) for node in nodes])
for edge in edges:
    graph[edge[0]].add(edge[1])
    graph[edge[1]].add(edge[0])
print graph
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an off-the-wall way: just pretend that your input grammar is python!

```
import ast
d = {}
_s1, s2 = (node for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(inp)) if isinstance(node, ast.Set))

for tup in s2.elts:
    n1,n2 = tup.elts
    d.setdefault(n1.id,set()).add(n2.id)
    d.setdefault(n2.id,set()).add(n1.id)
```

gives

```
d
Out[69]: {'A': set(['B', 'C']), 'B': set(['A', 'C']), 'C': set(['A', 'B'])}
```